# c# XmlSchema.Write method puts minOccurs before element name

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to replicate the output of a program that uses the DataSet.WriteXml method to write the xml schema. It puts minOccurs="0" at the end of each element:

```
 <xs:element name="record_type" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
```

When I try to write the schema like this:

```
XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(xsd_FileStream, null);
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(FileName, null);
xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument(true);
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("NewDataSet");

schema.Write(xmlWriter);
```

I get elements that look like this instead:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="record_type" type="xs:string" />
```

Answer (score 1):

www.w3.org Section 3.1 Says that

> Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant.

So, you do not need to have concern about the order of the attributes.

[Another Reference on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18067677/1118978)